# Using red5recorder in Asp.Net page

Tags: asp.net, red5

I have setup the red5 server on my local machine and want to create a Asp.Net application which will have a recorder module (red5recorder) to enable recording the video using the client webcam and microphone. Have gone through the red5recorder site, could only find some javascript functions to be called for recording, playing etc. Dont know how to use the recorder in the page.